# OpenLayers 3 show/hide layers

Tags: openlayers-3

I am creating an application which utilises a map created and managed by the OpenLayers 3 library. I want to be able to switch which layer is visible using the zoom level (i.e. zoom out to get an overview of countries, zoom in to get an overview of cities). There are three categories of layers (3 different zoom levels), and within each category there are 3 colours which the pins I am using could be (which are all separate layers as well) so in total there are 9 layers.

What I want is to develop the ability to filter which layers are displayed, which means showing/hiding the existing layers depending on which zoom level we are at.

There is some code to demonstrate how the map is generated and how one type of layer is generated but if there is more detail required please let me know. I don't believe there will be an issue with this, however.

```
function setUpMap(vectorLayers, $scope){

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.808981, 46.609599]),
        zoom: 4
      });

    map = new ol.Map({
       target: 'map',
       layers: vectorLayers,
       overlays: [overlay],
       view: view
     });

    view.on("change:resolution", function(e){
        var oldValue = e.oldValue;
        var newValue = e.target.get(e.key);
        if (newValue > 35000){
            if (oldValue < 35000)
                //This is where I will show group 1
        } else if (newValue > 10000){
            if (oldValue < 10000 || oldValue > 35000)
                //This is where I will show group 2
        } else {
            if (oldValue > 10000)
                //This is where I will show group 3
        }
    });

    addClickEventsToMapItems($scope);

}
```

I tried something like this and got no success:

```
function showLayer(whichLayer){
    vectorLayers[1].setVisibility(false);
    vectorLayers[2].setVisibility(false);
    vectorLayers[3].setVisibility(false);
    vectorLayers[whichLayer].setVisibility(true);
}
```

I am open to suggestions. Please let me know! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the `resolution:change` event on your `ol.Map` instance:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function (e) {
   if (map.getView().getZoom() > 0) {
       vector.setVisible(true);
   }
   if (map.getView().getZoom() > 1) {
       vector.setVisible(false);
   }
});
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/szSCMh6raZfHi9s6vzQX?p=preview

It's also worth to take a look at the `minResolution` and `maxResolution` options of `ol.layer` which can switch automaticly for you. But it works by using the view's resolution, not the zoomfactor:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/min-max-resolution.html

Comment: I am using that function and it isn't working... vector.setVisible(true) isn't working. The event listener is working, though.

Comment: Works for me as you can see in the example, perhaps you can share how you defined your layers?

Answer (score 3):

why dont you use `minResolution`/`maxResolution` parameters during vector layer initialasation, check the api [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html)
If you dont know the resolution but you know only the scale, use the following function to get the resolution out of the scale

```
function getResolutionFromScale(scale){
var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
var res = scale / (mpu * 39.37 * dpi); 
return res;
}
```